# Woocommerce internal server error on checkout

Tags: php, .htaccess, wordpress, woocommerce

I am experiencing this weird problem with my htaccess file everytime I tried to checkout on my woocommerce site. This is the htaccess file I currently have..

```
# BEGIN REMOVE SLUG CUSTOM POST TYPE RULES
RewriteRule ^slider/(.+)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]
# END REMOVE SLUG CUSTOM POST TYPE RULES


# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

but its strangely become like this after I checkout

```
# BEGIN REMOVE SLUG CUSTOM POST TYPE RULES
RewriteRule ^slider/(.+)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]
# END REMOVE SLUG CUSTOM POST TYPE RULES


# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
Rewrit
```

and 500 server error prompt up instead of showing thank you page but its all working if I fixed the htaccess file manually and refresh the same page, thank you page will show and also order was recorded fine even if I don't fixed the htaccess file.

I created my own woocommerce child theme for this site and I am using only two plugins called "Remove slug from custom post type" and "SEO Ultimate" to make the product and category urls as I needed and both plugins seems to be changing htaccess on the fly, but I am not really sure why only on checkout it makes htaccess file cut off like that...? These are the url where I'am getting this error

http://mysite.dev/checkout/order-received/709?key=wc_order_53db13e068104

its redirect to this url after I correct htaccess manually.
http://mysite.dev/checkout/order-received/709/?key=wc_order_53db13e068104

also this error doesn't occur all the time please help!

Comment: You should check the error log for more details about the error. We can't guess what the problem is based on this information.
I'm not an expert in Apache, but that .htaccess seams fine.

Comment: I did checked error log and its already clean.. I know I am also guessing pretty much since I don't know inside out of woocommerce... The problem is happening right after checkout ajax request which is done successfully but redirected to 500 error. But now it seems working again when I switched between woocommerce default and my theme. But I know it will come up again sometime later..

Comment: There should be some log output if you get internal server error if you haven't disabled that in your config.

Comment: 500 error was because of htaccess I think not because of php errors, I have some php errors in error logs which are dated yesterday and I already fixed those.

Comment: But none of the rules in you .htaccess has anything to do with checkout specifically. I can't see how this is related to your problem.
Do you get anything more than the standard "500: internal server error" message? Check the full response in your dev tools.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error then I just added the following line to my wp-config.php

```
define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );
```

This will turn on WordPress debugging feature and write the log into file instead of displaying it on your front-end.

After that executing the webpage again. I got the exact function name causing error in my log file and I just resolved that function issue.

Comment: and which function was it and how did you resolve it?

Comment: functions may be different in your case. I tried commenting that line and it worked